# Xamarin Android TCP-SocketException -> invalid arguments

Tags: sockets, tcp, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wrote an android App using Xamarin.Android which connects to a server running on my local computer using tcp sockets. This works fine as long as both my android device and my computer are connected to my router. Now i tried the same thing with my phone connected to a hostednetwork createt by my computer but I get an error of invalid arfuments when calling  socket.connect(ipendpoint) with the Errorcode 10022.

The following is the relevant code:

```
Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPHostEntry HostDnsEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry ("192.168.173.1");
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint (HostDnsEntry.AddressList [0], 6667);
sck.Connect (endpoint);
```

As I said the code works fine within my routers local network. Where could be the problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are binding the socket and the line that is throwing the Socket Exception.

Answer (score 0):

#### Socket Error 10022

> Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.

Your socket server does not appear to be bound and listening to `192.168.173.1:6667`

Can you connect to your socket-based server from your PC using the following on your PC?

```
telnet 192.168.173.1 6667
```

(Or some other tcp tool, like `nc`, or does `192.168.173.1:6667` show up as listening in a `port scan`, or `netstat`?)

If not, your server socket is not bound to that interface/port and thus your Android device and/or emulator will not be able to connect to it either.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. I bound the server to any ip address of my computer and i can coonect to it using the telnet client. I also can find it using a port scanner on my androidphone. So that is very strange. Do you have any other ideas.

Comment: @hoxplus Connecting to your Android via `adb`, can you ping that address from the device? (i.e. `adb shell ping -c1 192.168.173.1`)

Comment: well that does also work. Suddenly the code throws a new error although i didn´t change anything. Now it throws when I call       IPHostEntry HostDnsEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry ("192.168.137.1"); The errortext says "Could not resolve host '192.168.137.1'"

Comment: now i got the original error again. this seems pretty random to me